# Street View Service: Adding street view to the search results

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

Hi need some idea/suggestion on using the street view,
i am getting place details  implementing a search by type  using the places Api
below is my search places code

```
function SearchData(type){

    $('#placedata').empty();
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(searchLatitute), parseFloat(searchLongitute));
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    center: myLatlng,
                    zoom: 10});
        var request = {location: myLatlng,rankBy: google.maps.places.RankBy.DISTANCE,types: [type]};
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.search(request, callback);
  }

  function callback(results, status,pagination) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var place = results[i];
        createMarker(place);

  function createMarker(place) {
        var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({map: map,zIndex: 100,position: place.geometry.location});

    var request = {reference: place.reference};
    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.getDetails(request, function(details, status) {//alert("address  "+details.formatted_address);
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        $('#placedata').append('<tr><td><a href='+details.url+'>'+details.name+'</a></td></tr>');

    }
});
```

i am displaying the result in my webpage..what i wanna implement is to add a street view to each address. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Simply use the image provided by the [Static StreetView-Image-API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/#url_parameters).  But
   if there is no image available for this place you'll get a
   error-image.
2. request StreetView-details for the given location by using [getPanoramaByLocation()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewService), what allows you to handle the case when no Image is available for this place, but requires a further request, and you'll also be able to load a Panorama.

---

**`<edit>`**

As requested, the case #2 can be handled like this(the following code is a replacement for your current service.getDetails()-callback):

```
function(details, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {

      //create streetViewService-object once
      if(!window.streetViewService)window.streetViewService 
        = new google.maps.StreetViewService;   


        (function(d){
          //append the tr to the table, note the additional td and div
          //thats where the panorama will be placed later
          var target=$('<tr><td><a href='+
                        d.url+'>'+d.name+
                       '</a></td><td><div/></td></tr>');

          target.appendTo('#placedata');

          //get the panorama
          window.streetViewService
            .getPanoramaByLocation(d.geometry.location,
                                   50,
                                   function(r,status){
                                   //check if there was an result
                                   if(status==google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK){
                                    //create the panorama
                                    new google.maps
                                      .StreetViewPanorama(
                                          $('td:last div:last',target)
                                            .css({width:200,height:200})[0],
                                         {pano:r.location.pano});
                                  }
                                  else{
                                    $('td:last div:last',target)
                                     .text('no panorama available');
                                  }
                                });
        })(details)


    }
}
```

Comment: hi..tried your code but noting is working for me...am i doing something wrong..here is my complete code i tried http://pastebin.com/2Kx1uAK6..how iam supposed to get streetview for each address?

Comment: I did not suggest to use the code and paste it somewhere. Your code contains different syntax-errors. My suggestion was this: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8R3jQ/

Comment: @ Dr.Molle  Thank you..it looks good..i would like to display all the info of the place like address,phone,website..iam doing the f0llowing but not getting   http://pastebin.com/0xV0bxhK

Comment: :) yeahh..Thank You Molle for you time